# No funciona el lanzar el modal automatico

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap, modal

he estado intentando a traves de una funcion llamada "definir()" abrir un modal cuando cambie los campos. El problema es que sin importar donde lo ponga, el modal nunca se ejecuta. Intente ponerlo que se abriera cuando cargara la pagina, pero tampoco funciono. Dejo aqui el codigo del modal y la funcion "definir()" Estoy muy confundido, porque es solo una linea de codigo y no puedo entender porque no funciona. Tengo los scripts de Jquery y JS puestos, aun asi, no se ejecuta al cambiar los campos

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                    function definir(){
                      $('#modalRegisterForm').modal('show')
                      var from = document.getElementById('from').value;
                      var to = document.getElementById('to').value;
                      var size = document.getElementById('size').value;
                      
                      location.href="<?= base_url(); ?>client/dashboard?from="+from+"&to="+to+"&size="+size;
                      return false;
                    }
                </script>
```

```
<div class="modal fade" name="modalRegisterForm" id="modalRegisterForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalRegisterForm"
        aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header text-center">
              <h4 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold">Nueva Encomienda</h4>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body mx-3">
            
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">

                <i class="material-icons">vpn_key</i>
                <input type="text" id="guia" name="guia" value=" <?php echo codigoc();?>" class="form-control validate">
                <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-name">Guia</label>

                </div>
                
                <div class="col-md-4">



                <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                    function definir(){
                      $('#modalRegisterForm').modal('show')
                      var from = document.getElementById('from').value;
                      var to = document.getElementById('to').value;
                      var size = document.getElementById('size').value;
                      
                      location.href="<?= base_url(); ?>client/dashboard?from="+from+"&to="+to+"&size="+size;
                      return false;
                    }
                </script>

                <!--<form id="form" name="form">-->
                
                <i class="material-icons">flag</i>
                <select onchange="return definir();" id="from" name="from" class="form-control validate">


                <?php 

                $idfrom = $_GET['from'];
                $saveFrom = $this->login_model->saveFrom($idfrom);
                
                if(isset($_GET['from'])){

                  foreach($saveFrom->result() as $fSaves) {

                    echo '<option value="'.$fSaves->id.'">'.$fSaves->desde.'</option>'; 

                  }

                }else{

                  echo '<option value="1">Zonas</option>'; 

                }

                ?>
                
                  <?php 

                    

                    $from = $this->login_model->from();

                      foreach($from->result() as $f2) {

                        echo '<option value="'.$f2->id_zone.'">'.$f2->desde.'</option>'; 
  
  
                      }

                  ?>

                </select>
                <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-name">Desde</label>

                </div>
                
                <div class="col-md-4">
                
                <i class="material-icons">outlined_flag</i>
                <select onchange="return definir();" id="to" name="to" class="form-control validate">


                <?php 

                $idto = $_GET['to'];
                $saveTo = $this->login_model->saveTo($idto);
                
                if(isset($_GET['to'])){

                  foreach($saveTo->result() as $ftSaves) {

                    echo '<option value="'.$ftSaves->id.'">'.$ftSaves->hasta.'</option>'; 

                  }

                }else{

                  echo '<option value="1">Zonas</option>'; 

                }

                ?>
                  <?php 

                    $to = $this->login_model->to();
  

                    foreach($to->result() as $f3) {

                      echo '<option value="'.$f3->id.'">'.$f3->hasta.'</option>';  

                    }

                  ?>

                </select>
                <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-name">Hasta</label>

                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row">
                
                <div class="col-md-10">
                
                <center>
                <i class="material-icons">drafts</i>
                </center>
                <select onchange="return definir();" id="size" name="size" class="form-control validate">

                <?php 

                $idsize = $_GET['size'];
                $saveSize = $this->login_model->saveSize($idsize);
                
                if(isset($_GET['size'])){

                  foreach($saveSize->result() as $fsSaves) {

                    echo '<option value="'.$fsSaves->id.'">'.$fsSaves->description.'</option>'; 

                    $costSize = $fsSaves->cost;

                  }

                }else{

                  echo '<option value="1">Tamano</option>'; 

                }

                ?>
                  <?php 

                    $size = $this->login_model->size();
  

                    foreach($size->result() as $f4) {

                      echo '<option value="'.$f4->id.'">'.$f4->description.'</option>'; 

                    }

                  ?>

                </select>
                <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-name">Tamaño</label>

                </div>

                <?php
                
                if(isset($_GET['from'])){

                  //$idfrom = $_GET['from'];
                  $zone = $this->login_model->cost($idfrom);
          
                  
                                
                  foreach($zone->result() as $f5) {

                    $costZone = $f5->cost;
    

                ?>
                
                <div class="col-md-2">
                <center>
                <i class="material-icons">gps_fixed</i>
                
                <input type="text" id="orangeForm-name"  value="<?php echo $f5->zone;
            
                      }
                }else{
                  echo 
                  '
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                  <center>
                  <i class="material-icons">gps_fixed</i>
                  
                  <input type="text" id="orangeForm-name"  value="Zona';
                }
                ?>" class="form-control validate" style="margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;">
                <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-name">Zona</label>
                </center>

                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row">
              
                <div class="col-md-12">
                
                <center>
                <i class="material-icons">local_atm</i>
                </center>
                <input type="text" id="orangeForm-name" class="form-control validate"
                
                <?php if(isset($costZone) && isset($costSize)){ ?>
                value="<?php $total = $costZone + $costSize.'$';
                             preg_replace('([^A-Za-z0-9])', '', $total);
                             echo $total;
                } ?>">
                <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-name">Costo</label>

                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row">
              
                <div class="col-md-12">
                
                <center>
                <i class="material-icons">description</i>
                </center>
                <input type="text" id="orangeForm-name" class="form-control validate">
                <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="orangeForm-name">Descripcion de la encomienda</label>

                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row">
              
                <div class="col-md-1">
               
                <i class="material-icons">sync</i>
                <input type="checkbox" id="round" name="round" class="form-control validate">
                <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="round">¿Ida y vuelta?</label>

                </div>
              </div>
           

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-deep-orange">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="text-center">
        <a href="" class="btn btn-default btn-rounded mb-4" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalRegisterForm">Launch
          Modal Register Form</a>
      </div>
```

Como veran hay campos que tienen la funcion onChange puestos pero son solo los 3 primeros. Por favor cualquier ayuda estaria bien. Gracias. Adjunto imagen del modal abierto

[image: Modal abierto]

Comment: Te recomiendo que le des una leida sobre como funciona jQuery Modal aca te dejo su documentacion: https://jquerymodal.com/ te muestra ejemplos practicos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

donde dice aria-hidden debes colocar false, cuando esta en true quiere decir que por defecto estara cerrado el modal.

```
<div class="modal fade" name="modalRegisterForm" id="modalRegisterForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalRegisterForm"
    aria-hidden="false">
```

Por otro lado no entiendo muy bien exactamente que es lo que quieres hacer. Eso que te pase es para que abra automaticamente cuando cargue la pagina pero no entiendo bien para que esa funcion definir con js.

Comment: Ya pude resolver, sucedia que cargue los scripts en el footer y por alguna razon este no los leia. Los cambie al header. Gracias por tu ayuda, igualmente tuve que cambiar el aria-hidden a false

Comment: claro, los script siempre se cargan al principio, js es asincronico, entonces se esta creando el modal antes de cargar los script, entonces simplemente no lo reconoce.